Network namespace stopped working after hardware change
A couple of days ago I had a motherboard failure and as a result I bought a new computer. I swapped in the old hard drives and after a couple of hiccups, everything was nearly the same again. It is running Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon and since it's literally the same drives, nothing but the hardware and some drives has changed.
I have been using openvpn to connect to a vpn service in a network namespace using, I think, a relatively common strategy of having an 'up' 'route-up' 'down' script that openvpn uses. I did change the dev name from 'eth0' to 'enp1s0' as that's how the new ethernet device showed up. This is the 'up' portion:
ip netns add vpn
ip link add dev veth0 address "<mac address>" type veth peer name veth1
ip link set veth0 netns vpn
ip link set veth1 up
ip link set enp1s0 down
ip addr flush dev enp1s0
ip link set enp1s0 up
ip link add br0 type bridge
ip link set enp1s0 master br0
ip link set veth1 master br0
ip addr add xx.xx.xx.58/24 dev br0
ip link set br0 up
ip route flush default
ip route add default via xx.xx.xx.1

ip netns exec vpn ip link set lo up
ip netns exec vpn ip addr flush dev veth0
ip netns exec vpn ip addr add xx.xx.xx.100/24 dev veth0
ip netns exec vpn ip link set veth0 up

ip netns exec vpn /usr/sbin/iptables -F OUTPUT
ip netns exec vpn /usr/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -d $trusted_ip -j ACCEPT
ip netns exec vpn /usr/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -d xx.xx.xx.0/24 -j ACCEPT
ip netns exec vpn /usr/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
ip netns exec vpn /usr/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
ip netns exec vpn /usr/sbin/iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

ip link set dev "$1" up netns vpn mtu "$2"
ip netns exec vpn ip addr add dev "$1" \
        "$4/${ifconfig_netmask:-30}" \
        ${ifconfig_broadcast:+broadcast "$ifconfig_broadcast"}

and then 'route-up':
ip netns exec vpn ip route add default via "$route_vpn_gateway" dev tun0

I've had this working for years and now when it runs, the global namespace and the netns can ping each other, but nothing else.
I've confirmed that /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward is still 1.
I've confirmed that all of the routing globally and in the netns looks like I expect and as it always has.
I've confirmed that the global iptables forward policy is "ACCEPT".
I've tried walking through the script steps one-by-one any number of times, and there are no errors but it never works.
I've tried walking through a number of really basic netns tutorials to try and sort out what happening. For example this one: Linux Network Namespaces, An Easy Guide To Establish And Link Seperated Environments
It creates and connects two network namespaces by two different methods: with a bridge and without one. Perhaps notably, the second method described using a bridge, would not work for me and the two netns's couldn't ping each other.
I'm at a bit of a loss as to why this might has suddenly stopped working. Any suggestions?

Do you have any NAT rules on the host that refer to the old network name?

@StephenHarris: Nope!
